# discord.py python how can i do like this im newbie

Tags: python, discord.py

How can i make bot discord like this
when i text the word in #textchanel "(Showing concern) Jack."
The bot will randomly reply to messages of showing concern to Jack

" It's okay, Jack " , " Jack are you okay? " , Etc

And when you type "(Angry)Jack"

bot will randomly reply to messages of angry to jack

" f*ck you Jack " , " Jack what the f*ck you doing " , " Jack lol " Etc

But the text "Jack" can be anything someone sends a message, for example:
" Showing concern billie "
or
" Showing concern everyone "

I'm new to this

user send text in #textchanel

user : "Showing concern (Any message a person sends)."

Bot randomly reply

BOT : " It's okay, Jack " , " Jack are you okay? " , Etc

And when you type "(Angry)Jack"

bot will randomly reply to messages of angry to jack

BOT : " f*ck you Jack " , " Jack what the f*ck you doing " , " Jack lol " Etc

But the text "Jack" can be anything someone sends a message, for example:
" Showing concern billie "
or
" Showing concern everyone "

Comment: What did you try? What have you got done so far? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. If you're a beginner, take a look at the [Quickstart guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) on the documentation. and once that's working you can play around and change it as need be. Then look up tutorials or look for other SO questions; there's plenty of information already on the internet for what you want to do - sending a message in response to someone's elses is quite basic stuff and it's clear you've not tried to look at the guides/docs/tutorials at all.

Comment: _If_ you get stuck going through all that, _then_ ask questions.

Answer (score -1):

As you are new using the package, try using the `on_message` event.

```py
import discord, random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):

  try:
    bot.process_command(message)
  except:
    pass

  if message.channel.id == 1234567890:
    if "(showing concern) jack" in message.content.lower():
      replies = ["It's okay Jack", "Jack, are you okay?"]

      reply = random.choice(replies)
      await message.channel.send(reply)
    elif "(angry) jack" in message.content.lower():
      replies = ["F*ck you Jack", "Jack, wtf...", "What are you doing Jack!?"]
      
      reply = random.choice(replies)
      await message.channel.send(reply)

bot.run("token_goes_here")
```

Hope this served! Any other doubt comment in my answer and I will try to help you.

Comment: Doing `import random` twice in two separate if statements is bad practice. It would be better to just import at the top of the file. Additionally, your spacing doesn't conform to Python [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and is only two spaces and not four per indententation level (I would edit this but edit queue is full). The strings in your `replies` list also use a single ', but you also use `'` as punctuation - it would be better to use double quotation marks here as your code will currently just error out due to python interpreting the legit punctuation as the end of the string.

Comment: [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) also doesn't work like that. Need to use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) on a list of values.

Comment: NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Comment: Yeah yeah made some mistakes, replied in mobile so didn't have all things I need, all fixed @ESloman